# WooCommerce order complete email logic

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, order, email

Can someone helps me to understand the logic of WooCommerce for sending email on a completed order?

If I'm not wrong, the mail is send when the order is marked complete, but I'm not able to find the code that actually do it.
All I can see is the action hook `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` that trigger the sending mechanism inside `WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order`, but I don't know how that hook is used inside WooCommerce plugin... When and where is it trigger?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

After some test and research, I think I've found where it is trigger.
If I understood it correctly (this is simplistic approach of all functions and hooks used in process);

1) The Order is save (WC_Order->save())

2) The status set before is used to create an action hook ('woocommerce_order_status_completed')

3) Inside WC_Emails, ::send_transactional_email() is hooked to this action ('woocommerce_order_status_completed')

4) WC_Emails::send_transactional_email(), execute the action hook ('woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification') which is used to send an email.

Please tell me, if you see some misunderstanding about the process.
Hopes it helps anybody looking for the same.